# Laravel belongsToMany with LeftJoin Scope

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

I have table
articles (id, status)
article_Translations (name)

article_categories (id,status)
article_category_translations (name)

and pivot table
article_article_category (article_category_id and article_id)

They have such relations and scope:

Article model

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(ArticleCategory::class);
}

public function scopeTranslation($query)
{
    $query->leftJoin('article_translations', 'id', '=', 'article_translations.article_id')->where('article_translations.locale', config('app.locale'));
}
```

Article category model

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
}

public function scopeTranslation($query)
{
    $query->leftJoin('article_category_translations', 'id', '=', 'article_category_translations.article_category_id')->where('article_category_translations.locale', config('app.locale'));
}
```

I need to display a list of articles and indicate category names in them

in controller

```
$articles = Article::translation()->with(['categories' => function ($query) {
    $query->translation();
}])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);
```

in view

```
@foreach($articles as $article)
    {{ $article->name }}
    @foreach ($article->categories as $category)
        {{ $category->name }}
    @endforeach
@empty
```

but $category doesn't have $category ->name from article_categor_translations table
please help me very much((

Answer (score 0):

Normally while joining when you have multiple tables with same column name, you should make alias for them. For example, let's say you have two tables products and category. Both table a common column name called 'name'. When you gonna make join between them one of them will stay and the other one will be hidden. So for those cases you should make alias for them. Something like this

```
select t1.name as product_name, t2.name as category_name
from products as t1
left join categories as t2 on t1.category_id = t2.id
```

In your case, make sure you are selecting the columns from each table you are joining as make alias form them to avoid collision. You might want to user `DB::raw()` in this case.